# Convert PDF to Word Using Libreoffice in terminal

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, pdf, file-format, convert-command

I am using the following libreoffice command to convert my **pdf files into word(doc)**

```
lowriter --headless --infilter='writer_pdf_import' --convert-to doc:"MS Word 2007 XML" sample.pdf
```

After converting the output document is having each line bordered with a rectangular box. But if I use the same command with **MS Word 97** it is working perfectly.

```
 lowriter --headless --infilter='writer_pdf_import' --convert-to doc:"MS Word 97" sample.pdf
```

I don't know what is the mistake in the first command. Please help me with this. And also suggest me if I need to add any other attributes that will improve the efficiency and quality of conversion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. But I need some command to convert the files. The post you shared is for converting the files using GUI. Cheers!

Comment: Does this website help you? https://sarata.com/manpages/lowriter.1.html

Comment: @Raffles No. They gave the list of attributes but doesn't mention what we need to use to convert pdf to word.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using LibreOffice for a long now but still can't understand it how does it work with different files.

I'm using the below command to convert PDF to WORD. You may try :

```
libreoffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx input.pdf
```

This is working perfectly.

Comment: Does not work for me. I got: Error: source file could not be loaded. I had put the full path but does not work

Comment: try executing the command when you are in same directory with the input.pdf

Comment: THANK YOU this works ! For me there is no option in the gui to save/convert pdf's to anything but text ----- the commandline comes to the rescue :-)

Comment: Thanks very much -- One little value add.  I'm using `LibreOffice` from `flathub`.  You can run: `flatpak run org.libreoffice.LibreOffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx input.pdf`

Answer (score 3):

Did you try with `soffice`?

```bsh
soffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx sample.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this post: [Can I convert a PDF file to a Word File? - Ask LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/68131/can-i-convert-a-pdf-file-to-a-word-file/)

No, LibreOffice will not convert a PDF to a DOC (or ODT) or so.

If your pdf is having texts and not images you can open it with LibreOffice draw and then copy and paste and edit & save document as you need.

Comment: It will convert. The only problem is no one shared the exact code to convert. My first command is working but with some errors. The second command is working but not efficient. All I need is some expert help

Comment: was the OP asking about MS Word or LO Write?